# Сместить на одну позицию вниз в датасете

Tags: python

Нужно сместить на одну позицию вниз данные из колонки "buy_price_nds" чтобы посчитать динамику к предыдущей дате. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Таблица то в чём у вас - Pandas?

Comment: Почитайте про метод shift в pandas. Вообще, ответы на такие вопросы легко находятся в документации.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про `Pandas`, то используйте метод `shift`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': range(5)})
df['prev_price'] = df['price'].shift()
df
```

Вывод:

| index | price | prev_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.0 |
| 3 | 3 | 2.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3.0 |

Вообще, если нужна сразу разница с предыдущим значением, то на этот случай тоже есть отдельный готовый метод `diff`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогли!